# Is my implementation of this Java Bytecode instruction correct?

Tags: java

I had been working on a project called J2CPP: a Java Bytecode to C++ convertor. It is a JNI-AOT Compiler, which means it uses the Java Native Interface to slide in the AOT images. I had been struggling with this Java Bytecode Instruction Implementation. I had difficulties implementing a Java Bytecode instruction. Can someone tell me is my implementation correct?

```cpp
    public : void __dup_x2()
    {
        StackItem* stackItem1 = Pop();
        StackItem* stackItem2 = Pop();
        StackItem* stackItem3 = Pop();
        bool lng = false;
        lng |= (stackItem2->longValue == nullptr);
        lng |= (stackItem2->doubleValue == nullptr);
        if(lng){
            Push(StackItem1);
            Push(StackItem2);
            Push(StackItem1);
        } else{
            Push(StackItem1);
            Push(StackItem3);
            Push(StackItem2);
            Push(StackItem1);
        }
    }
```

Comment: First, I'm pretty sure it doesn't compile because you use both `stackItem1` and `StackItem1` (check the case). Second, you never push back `stackItem3` if `stackItem2` is a long or double. Ideally you don't want to `pop` it at all if that's the case (i.e. move the last `Pop` into the else-branch.

Comment: Also: the JVM spec assumes that `long` and `double` values take up two stack items, so the behaviour in that case is automagic. If your AOT does *not* implement them this way, then you'll have many special cases like this (and will probably miss a few).

Answer (score 0):

I finally found out a solution. I would use stack item splitting to simulate the standard JVM behavior of storing double and long values as 2 words.